# Unhandled exception: PyObject_GetAttrString can't run python function in c++

Tags: python, c++, winapi

So I'm trying to run a python function in my windows app but I'm having some trouble with this line here:
`pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"download");`

this is the full code:

```
if (SendMessage(download, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0)) {
            Py_Initialize();
            // CODE TO RUN PYTHON FUNCTION
            PyObject* output = PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop");
            PyObject* ytlink = PyUnicode_FromString("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9cyeZfLeQc&ab_channel=FIRSTRoboticsCompetition");
            PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pFunc, * pArgs, * pValue;
            pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"Downloader.py");
            pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
            pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"download");
            pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(2, ytlink, output);
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_Finalize();
        }
```

I was following this tutorial: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-quickly-embed-python-in-your-c-application-23c19694813

I'm really new to running python in c++ so I'm not sure whether or not I'm missing something obvious or whether there is something else going on.

this was the exact error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF8F278B13 (python310_d.dll) in YTDownloader.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
```

Comment: You must be careful  about the datatype when delivering parameters to Python function.

Comment: After every Python C API function call, you need to check whether the return value is NULL to see if an error occurred.

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer, presumably the return value from `PyImport_Import`. You'll want to implement error handling. The documentation will tell you how each call reports errors. Besides, those `(char*)` casts are wrong, in two ways, even. Every API call where you're applying a cast expects a `char const*`. So not only are you casting to the *wrong* type, it's also unnecessary since the string literals will decay into the correct pointer type automatically.

Comment: @IInspectable so I don't have to cast the strings at all?

Comment: You've called `PyUnicode_FromString` twice without casting the string literal already. I fail to understand the question.